# Error consuming web service due to lack of certificate in java (XML SOAP based)

Tags: java, web-services, soap, certificate, webservice-client

I need to consume a web service which was built under Https in java. 
The Web Service Client was generated using Eclipse and to call it I use the following code:

```
ServicioTimbradoPruebasLocator ServicioTimbradoLocator = new ServicioTimbradoPruebasLocator();
                            ServicioTimbradoPruebasSoap ServicioTimbrado = ServicioTimbradoLocator.getServicioTimbradoPruebasSoap();
                            javax.xml.rpc.Stub s =((javax.xml.rpc.Stub)ServicioTimbrado);
                            s._setProperty(javax.xml.rpc.Stub.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "XXXXXXXX");
                            s._setProperty(javax.xml.rpc.Stub.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "psswd");          
                            String resultado = ServicioTimbrado.generaTimbre(xml.getBytes());
                            System.out.println("resultado: " +resultado);
```

On this line **String resultado = ServicioTimbrado.generaTimbre(xml.getBytes());** I get the following error:

```
AxisFault
     [java]  faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
     [java]  faultSubcode: 
     [java]  faultString: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
     [java]  faultActor: 
     [java]  faultNode: 
     [java]  faultDetail: 
     [java]     {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
     [java]     at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at org.apache.axis.components.net.JSSESocketFactory.create(JSSESocketFactory.java:186)
     [java]     at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.getSocket(HTTPSender.java:191)
     [java]     at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.writeToSocket(HTTPSender.java:404)
     [java]     at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:138)
     [java]     at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
     [java]     at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
     [java]     at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
     [java]     at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
     [java]     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
     [java]     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
     [java]     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
     [java]     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
     [java]     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
     [java]     at mx.com.timbrado.test.cfdi.ServicioTimbradoPruebasSoapStub.generaTimbre(ServicioTimbradoPruebasSoapStub.java:107)
     [java]     at natura.facturacion.general.GuardarFacturaElectronicav2.doPost(GuardarFacturaElectronicav2.java:136) ...
```

I want to know if there is a way to send the certificate among with the webservice call. 
More information about the wsdl contract and the java generated files could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072079/consume-xml-soap-webservice-in-java)

Comment: Looks to me that it's more along the lines that the CA(s)'s listed in the cert's chain can't be verified, e.g. it's using a CA that java knows nothing about.

Comment: Ah... Spanish classes and methods.. it's been a long time since I worked with those.

Comment: In order to communicate, client and WS must share certificates. Each one having a keystore with an own private key to decipher input and a partner's public key to cipher output.

That path is configured in an XML file related to policies whose name I can't remember...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on the version of Java you are using, one of the "recent" updates to the 1.6 JRE/JDK include a significant change in the global CACerts (the Trusted authority that signs SSL Certificats, for instance Verisign) to include some of the new certificate types that are around.

I recommend upgrading to the latest versions of Java to see if that works, if not, Option 2 is...

Using [SSLPoke.java](https://code.google.com/p/educationau-utils/source/browse/trunk/java/EdAuUtils/src/main/java/au/edu/educationau/opensource/ssl/SSLPoke.java?spec=svn43&r=43) you can find out which certificates are missing, and the [InstallCert.java](https://code.google.com/p/java-use-examples/source/browse/trunk/src/com/aw/ad/util/InstallCert.java) to install them as follows;

1. java InstallCert webserver.domain.com:443
2. Copy the generated “jssecacerts” file to your “$JAVA_HOME\jre\lib\security” folder.

If this still causes issues, can you include the output from sslpoke, example usage;

```
# java SSLPoke webserver.domain.com 443
Successfully connected
```

If ALL that doesnt work, and you can get the certificate file (crt) you can manually import the file using the keytool command (cacerts is a file that will be created in your local working directory; ensure you move it into the java security folder in your JRE/JDK);

keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias AddTrustExternalCARoot -file cetificate.crt -keystore cacerts

Comment: I used the InstallCert.java class and it indicates that the certificate is correctly added to my javastore. A file named jsseacacerts is generated with this information. I copy this file to $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security and I get the same error. I try to manually import my certificate to my keystore with the following command: $JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool.exe -import -file mycert.cer -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass psswd and I get a java.ioFileNotFoundException <Access denied>

Comment: The SSLPoke throws me the following error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
 at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)...

Comment: It may be possible that there are multiple installations of Java on your machine, the InstallCert.java is the [recommended](http://blogs.oracle.com/gc/entry/unable_to_find_valid_certification) way of solving this problem.  Can you try running the InstallCert command using the same java runtimes that are operating your server container (I assume its in Tomcat/JBoss/Glassfish or similar?)

Comment: Works for me after following the guide from http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/. It guides how to use InstallCert.java. Ensure verification step is passed. Need to restart application server though.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this thread: [How to handle invalid SSL certificates with Apache HttpClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828775/httpclient-and-ssl)

Of course here you have a WSDL SOAP Web Service, there you have an Apache HTTP Client, but the error is the same and you can handle it in the same way (or ways).

You can:

> 1 - Force your program to accept **ANY** SSL certificate
>
> 2 - Download and install in your JVM the SSL certificate that you're missing

The 1st one is easier (in the most of the case), but you should use it **ONLY** before the release or you'll be easily exposed to a "Man in the middle attack". The 2nd (usually) a better choice.

Here there is a synthetic but well explained documantation to those 2 points described before with code samples:
http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/ssl.html